# Improve mesh, based on depth map

Tags: opencv, opengl, image-processing, 3d, mesh

I'm working on a focal lenght based 3D scan solution. I take a stack of images from the same scene, with different focal lenght, and select the sharpest layer pixel wisely. The main problem, is that intensive glare causes bad spots in the depth map.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea how to improve the results on triangle or depth map level?

Comment: with "improvement" you mean to filter out those bad reconstructions resulting in holes)? Or do you want to choose "better" layers even though there's glare (but that wouldnt be triangle/dm level?!?)?

Comment: I can use ideas on any level.

Comment: afair you can detect those "jumps" in triangle level by looking at the smalles inner angle of a triangle (they are very long and sharp). after removing the connections between jumps you might be able to identify possible bad reconstructed areas (small connected components) and have another look at the different layers there. But it might be better to analyze the code how the "sharpest" layer is selected, maybe you can identify bad regions there already ;)

Comment: The problem is, that there are sharp triangles on real peaks as well.

Comment: Thats why those regions are "possible" erroneous. After detecting them you must try to find out whats the difference between glare and real peak